# changing the background of JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, background, joptionpane

I change the background of JOptionPane with this code :

```
 UIManager.put("OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(204, 255, 255));
```

but the result doesn't look like what I expect

[image: The result.]

Comment: Looks like you might need to set the backgrounds of the components inside the JOptionPane to transparent.

Comment: A `JOptionPane` is a wonderful little utility **if used exactly as intended.** When it comes to customisation, it is often better to simply use a `JDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.BLUE);
UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.BLUE);
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "YOUR INFORMATION HERE");
```